# Fancybox - how to achieve this effect?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

This site seems to be using jquery fancybox, but none of the examples covered by fancybox do the same thing. The effect of showing the lightbox and the clicking on the lightbox disappearing into where it came from is very nice! Does anyone know how to achieve the same effect with fancybox?

http://www.glauce.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using fancybox **v1.3.4** and using documented API options but with different values as in the examples.

The effect you want is achieved using these options :

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'speedIn': 1000,
    'speedOut': 700
});​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2cTep/)**

... or the **[the same effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb3hR/)** closing on clicking the content without closing button.